# Receive JSON POST in PHP with ENTER in one of the field value

Tags: php, json

When "descriptions" field has "enter" (newline) API is failing.

Image to check all parameter sent by users

[image: a busy cat]

Below code to get the data from posted JSON.

```
     // get posted data
     $jason_value = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
     $crm_id = $jason_value->data->crmId;
     $descriptions = $jason_value->data->descriptions;
```

I would like to accept descriptions as a string one line.

descriptions = "10+ windows modern style 7057655959".

I do not have access to the program where the user enters the description where I can add validation and convert it to \n.

Getting below string after conversion

```
{ "jwt": "eyJ0", "data": { "crmId": "15876047", "geoconceptAppointmentId": "15876","geoconceptCustomerId": "15876047","status": "Rejected","appointmentDateTime": "","firstName": "Nick Test","lastName": "PA","address": "9112 RUE Tom","city": "MONTREAL","state": "QC","zip": "H2N1T1","country": "CAN","phoneNumber1": "5148332222","phoneNumber2": "5148332222","email": "nbskgg@gmail.com","dateEntry": "2019-06-20 12:02","dateModify": "2019-06-20 12:02","preferredWayToContact": "","textMsgFlag": "Y","hearAboutUs": "Referral","perferredTime": "Anytime","descriptions": "I have to call at 5" pm. ","worklog": "This is the comment ","rejectReason": "Area | Region","referredByDC": "09999","referredByStoreUsername": "store215","assignedUsername": "","createdByUsername": "np","modifiedByUsername": "np","btgMarket": "Montreal"}}
```

Comment: Ok.. so what is the problem?

Comment: @Andreas, API fails because there is "enter" newline in description

Comment: What is `$jason_value`? That variable does not exist in the code you've given us

Comment: @parttimeturtle , edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that in PHP7+, a literal tab or newline is going to cause the json parsing to fail. `file_get_contents("php://input")` returns a single string so I see no reason why you couldn't just filter that before you attempt to parse it. But maybe I'm missing something.

```
//Catch Unix OR DOS line endings, but not both
$filter = Array("\n","\n\r");
$replace = " ";
$cleanJSON = str_replace($filter, $replace, file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($cleanJSON));
```

I want to point out that after this point, your code is referencing a variable that does not exist: `$jason_value`

```
$crm_id = $jason_value->data->crmId;
$descriptions = $jason_value->data->descriptions;
```

To reference properties of the object you just created, go directly to `$data`:

```
$crm_id = $data->crmId;
$descriptions = $data->descriptions;
```

I expect that you'd want to replace the newline with a space but you may just want an empty string if what you're actually encountering has a space before the newline but that's impossible to tell from what we have.

Comment: thank you for the hint. Above code has some issues but used this simple version ```` $cleanJSON = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', file_get_contents("php://input")));

Comment: I'm having one more issue of having " in the description. Any hint of managing that? Example - "descriptions": " 10" windows, modsdsddernd ",

Comment: @Nick Without seeing what the JSON string looks like after you've filtered it, I couldn't tell you. You've already marked this as answered so if you're having a new issue you should open a new question so we can see what you've been doing since.

Comment: Please check a string in question